# speedup TFLite inference in python with multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, tensorflow-lite

I was playing with tflite and observed on my multicore CPU that it is not heavily stressed during inference time. I eliminated the IO bottleneck by creating random input data with numpy beforehand (random matrices resembling images) but then tflite still doesn't utilze the full potential of the CPU.

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/best_practices#tweak_the_number_of_threads) mentions the possibility to tweak the number of used threads. However I was not able to find out how to do that in the Python API. But since I have seen people using multiple interpreter instances for different models I thought one could maybe use multiple instances of the same model and run them on different threads/processes. I have written the following short script:

```
import numpy as np
import os, time
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
from multiprocessing import Pool


# global, but for each process the module is loaded, so only one global var per process
interpreter = None
input_details = None
output_details = None
def init_interpreter(model_path):
    global interpreter
    global input_details
    global output_details
    interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    print('done init')

def do_inference(img_idx, img):
    print('Processing image %d'%img_idx)
    print('interpreter: %r' % (hex(id(interpreter)),))
    print('input_details: %r' % (hex(id(input_details)),))
    print('output_details: %r' % (hex(id(output_details)),))

    tstart = time.time()

    img = np.stack([img]*3, axis=2) # replicates layer three time for RGB
    img = np.array([img]) # create batch dimension
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img )
    interpreter.invoke()

    logit= interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    pred = np.argmax(logit, axis=1)[0]
    logit = list(logit[0])
    duration = time.time() - tstart 

    return logit, pred, duration

def main_par():
    optimized_graph_def_file = r'./optimized_graph.lite'

    # init model once to find out input dimensions
    interpreter_main = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=optimized_graph_def_file)
    input_details = interpreter_main.get_input_details()
    input_w, intput_h = tuple(input_details[0]['shape'][1:3])

    num_test_imgs=1000
    # pregenerate random images with values in [0,1]
    test_imgs = np.random.rand(num_test_imgs, input_w,intput_h).astype(input_details[0]['dtype'])

    scores = []
    predictions = []
    it_times = []

    tstart = time.time()
    with Pool(processes=4, initializer=init_interpreter, initargs=(optimized_graph_def_file,)) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes

        results = pool.starmap(do_inference, enumerate(test_imgs))
        scores, predictions, it_times = list(zip(*results))
    duration =time.time() - tstart

    print('Parent process time for %d images: %.2fs'%(num_test_imgs, duration))
    print('Inference time for %d images: %.2fs'%(num_test_imgs, sum(it_times)))
    print('mean time per image: %.3fs +- %.3f' % (np.mean(it_times), np.std(it_times)) )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main_seq()
    main_par()
```

However the memory address of the interpreter instance printed via `hex(id(interpreter))` is the same for every process. The memory address of the input/output details is however different. Thus I was wondering if this way of doing it is potentially wrong even though I could experience a speedup? If so how could one achieve parallel inference with TFLite and python?

tflite_runtime version: 1.14.0 from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python) (the x86-64 Python 3.5 version)

python version: 3.5

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the same problem I need to solve.  FYI, I asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263640/does-tf-config-experimental-set-synchronous-execution-make-the-python-tensorfl.

Comment: @mherzog I used the above approach successfully and got separate processes with individual tflite interpreter instances working correctly and independently as far as I can tell from some test inference results. I think the memory address is the same since the processes are started identically and thus variables have the same memory layout. However this is just a guess and I didn't dive deeper into the issue.

Comment: i tried running something similar but just for comparison sake also ran it in a simple loop and the speedup i get for 50 data points using 5 workers (  vis a vis running these 50 images in a for loop ) is < 5% , so im guessing without using diff physical devices it isn't possible to truly process ANY TF code in parallel

Comment: @VikramMurthy the speedup in my case from single core to quad core was not exactly 4x but measurable faster around 3.5x. Thus the above code was working at the time of writing. However I dont know if things changed with later tf versions (although I highly doubt it). Maybe you should make sure that the speed bottleneck is the inference of the model and not some IO process?  Also starting more workers than available CPU cores might cause some slowdown.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this thread was created two and a half years ago.

For me,

```
import multiprocessing
tf.lite.Interpreter(modelfile, num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I did not set initializer and use the following codes to load model, and do inference in the same function to workaround this issue.

```
with Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
   results = pool.starmap(inference, enumerate(test_imgs))
```